# Access mdb not giving correct result

Tags: ms-access, odbc, oracle11g

I am using Access(2003) mdb file as front end of oracle 11g R2 as backend. I am using odbc connection to retrieve data from oracle database. But sometime mdb is displaying incorrect output.

For example, when I use the below query in mdb

```
SELECT *
FROM PLAN 
WHERE (((PLAN.BATCH_REF)="SSU080520122"));
```

and it is providing wrong result. But the same query is providing correct result in oracle.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the difference between the "wrong" result and the "correct" result? Your question is too unclear and ambiguous for us to provide you with meaningful help.

Comment: please provide an complete example: tables, data, select statement, expected result and actual result.

Comment: you have column named SSU080520122 in your database? Ouch.

Comment: How do you run that query ? A dao recordset in VBA ? A saved Access query ? A passthru query ?

Comment: Below is the detail scenario- I have a table called PLAN, where there are 30 columns are there and  BATCH_REF is one of the column ,I am trying to retrieve the records having  BATCH_REF=SU080520122. But it is showing the records having BATCH_REF= SSP030520121 (incorrect). IF I perform the same query in oracle (select * from PLAN where BATCH_REF= 'SSU080520122') showing the records having  BATCH_REF= SSU080520122 (Correct result).From Access end I tried to refresh PLAN (link table) through link table manager,also tried compact and repair option  but not working. Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is saved Access query

Comment: Have you tried a pass-thru query to see if the results are the same?

Comment: Did you try make filter on column BATCH_REF with value SSU080520122? What is the result?

Comment: Have you tried another application to make sure that the issue with not with the ODBC driver rather than MS Access ?

Answer (score 1):

`PLAN` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#P).  Using reserved words as table or column names can confuse the db engine.  Although this may not actually be the source of your trouble, it would be easy to rule it out as a contributor.  See if you get the results you expect with this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [PLAN] AS p
WHERE p.BATCH_REF="SSU080520122";
```